# How to disable template tab in compodoc?

Tags: angular, jsdoc

I was looking for doc generator tool for angular 2 application. I found compodoc to be useful for me.

In this tool, in the component section, I don't want to generate source code and template file.

--disableSourceCode is just disabling the source tab. But still, template tab is showing.

Is there a way to hide this template tab?

Also, is there any other tool for angular application?

[image]

Comment: will you please attach the screenshot of template tab , which you dont want to show ?

Comment: added the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Use disableTemplateTab to avoid generating template tab

```
npx compodoc -p tsconfig.doc.json --disableSourceCode --disableTemplateTab
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named `.compodocrc.json` and add the following snippet

```
{
  "disableSourceCode": true,
  "disableTemplateTab": true,
}
```

You can see other properties for configuring compodoc in `node_modules/@compodoc/compodoc/src/config/schema.json`